# 3g internet,sms unit and sd card unit

Tags: microcontroller, sd, sim

I am writing down the requirements i need to make a simple device which uses a micro-controller.The plan is simple.I have split the device core components into two.

Component 1

```
3G internet,sms unit and sd card unit
-----------------------------
sim card{any network carrier}
3G
sd card
```

Component 2

```
micro controller program
-----------------------------
-send sms,delete sms,read sms
-connect to the internet
-send email
```

In component 2,i have listed all the functions of the micro controller program.Is there a fully assembled device like i have listed in Component 1,that has a sim card reader,3g reception and an sd card to store the messages on sale anywhere or should i get individual components and build them myself?.

Thanks.

Comment: Google it!!!!!!

Comment: Okay.The ones i found on google before asking the question were using usb to connect.I thought this was bulky and had to ask.Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Several manufacturers sell modules like that.

Look for Telit, U-blox, etc...